# Identifying the date when row updated in Delta lake table

Tags: azure-synapse, delta-lake

We are using Delta lake table with 50 columns and few million rows in Azure environment.  We have updated few rows over the last one month but did not  maintained the value in "Updatedate" column available in table .  Now we have to update the column with date on which the row is updated.  Do we have any better way to capture the datetime when the row is updated from the delta table log.  Does the Delta table maintains Change Data Capture(CDC) for each row.

Answer (score 0):

CDF with Databricks Delta

To have the CDF feature available on a table, you must first enable the feature on said table. Below is an example of enabling CDF for the bronze table at table creation. You can also enable CDF on a table as an update to the table. In addition, you can enable CDF on a cluster for all tables created by the cluster.

[image]

For more information you can refer this [link1](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/06/09/how-to-simplify-cdc-with-delta-lakes-change-data-feed.html) and [link2](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/10/29/simplifying-change-data-capture-with-databricks-delta.html)